# Convert an ASCII grid file to GeoTIFF using Python?

Tags: python, gdal, convert, esri-ascii-raster

I have a ASCII grid raster format file. For example:

```
ncols 480
nrows 450
xllcorner 378923
yllcorner 4072345
cellsize 30
nodata_value -32768
43 2 45 7 3 56 2 5 23 65 34 6 32 54 57 34 2 2 54 6 
35 45 65 34 2 6 78 4 2 6 89 3 2 7 45 23 5 8 4 1 62 ...
```

How can I convert it to TIFF or any other raster using Python?

Comment: GIS software can convert asci to geotiff. No coding necessary. I use QGIS. Its free.

Answer (score 14):

The pseudo code version:

```
import gdal
import numpy

create the gdal output file as geotiff
set the no data value
set the geotransform 

numpy.genfromtxt('your file', numpy.int8) #looks like int from you example
reshape your array to the shape you need

write out the array.
```

A sample that will help you along - [from here](http://adventuresindevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/12/python-gdal-adding-geotiff-meta-data.html):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Import libs
    import numpy, os
    from osgeo import osr, gdal

    # Set file vars
    output_file = "out.tif"

    # Create gtif
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
    dst_ds = driver.Create(output_file, 174, 115, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte )
    raster = numpy.zeros( (174, 115) )

    # top left x, w-e pixel resolution, rotation, top left y, rotation, n-s pixel resolution
    dst_ds.SetGeoTransform( [ 14.97, 0.11, 0, -34.54, 0, 0.11 ] )

    # set the reference info 
    srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    srs.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84")
    dst_ds.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt() )

    # write the band
    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(raster)
```

Comment: and the values 14.97 and -34.54 are the top-left corner coordinates in WGS84 cooridanates?

Answer (score 12):

Alternative using [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html):

```
gdal_translate -of "GTiff" fname.asc outname.tif
```

Answer (score 7):

It may be easier to do a create copy, as your file is an AAIGrid and GTiff supports CreateCopy():

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr
drv = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
ds_in = gdal.Open('in.asc')
ds_out = drv.CreateCopy('out.tif', ds_in)
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
ds_out.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())
ds_in = None
ds_out = None
```

Any driver that supports CreateCopy can use this.

Comment: If you don't need to use python, bananafish is definitely right.

Comment: amazing, thanks! My input .asc file does come without a CRS. Is there a way to specify this CRS (GCS WGS 84) before writing the raster?

Comment: use SetProjection and a string.  You can get the string from osr.  See answer edit.