# Convert DTM txt file in GeoTIFF file

Tags: grass-gis, dem, geotiff-tiff

I have a DTM file, txt format, I would like to convert it into GeoTIFF, how can I do with the software grass?

```
ncols         1329
nrows         1152
xllcorner     1693884
yllcorner     5080341
cellsize      5
NODATA_value  -9999
1120.142 1119.698 1119.085 1118.423 1117.761 1117.164 1116.76 1116.354 1115.948 1115.546 1115.151 1114.757 1114.265 1113.767 1113.534 1113.508 1113.482 1113.955 1114.433 1114.91 1115.124
```

Comment: It depends on the format of the text file. Can you add some sample lines into your question?

Comment: Ok, Yes I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format looks like AAIGrid, see [How can I convert a ascii file to geotiff using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62343/how-can-i-convert-a-ascii-file-to-geotiff-using-python) for an example.

You can use gdal_translate to convert it to geotiff:

```
gdal_translate -of "GTiff" fname.asc outname.tif
```

The file extension `.asc` is important to tell gdal which format to use.

Or use the python code from the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

In GRASS GIS, use r.in.arc for the import or simply r.in.gdal (Menu: File -> Import raster data -> Common formats import). This should read the file right away.