# Reading ASCII Grid file cell value for given long/lat coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, esri-ascii-raster

I am trying to write a Python script which takes a set of long/lat coordinates as input and returns the  cell value corresponding to these coordinates

The ASCII Grid file is from PVGIS and contains solar radiation data.

Metadata:

```
Format: ESRI ascii grid
Map projection: geographic (latitude/longitude), ellipsoid WGS84
```

The header of the .asc file has this format:

```
ncols 5201
nrows 4001
xllcorner -65
yllcorner -35
cellsize 0.025
NODATA_value -9999
```

Is there a nice way of doing this without ArcGIS ?

I am looking into GeoPandas but have not yet found a way to solve this.

---

I have done some testing, initially with gdal but gave up on that for several reasons, so decided to make my own script inspired by world2pixel(). See my code below.

So now I have a couple of new questions/issues:

1.
If I input in my function readCellvalue() for example latitude 13.7 and longitude 60.7 my cellY value will become negative, which does not work very well. I am confused.

Should I simply put an abs() on it or is the problem somewhere else?

Can someone help me track this issue?

2.
Could someone clarify "ulY = 0.0 + 6 * 50.0" as suggested by @user1269942

My code:

`

```
import numpy as np

data = open('filename.asc')

def readCellvalue(lat, long):
   xllCorner = -65.0
   yllCorner = -35.0
   cellsize = 0.025

   lines = data.readlines()

   cellX = int((lat - xllcorner) / cellsize)
   cellY = int((yllCorner - long) / cellsize)

   line = lines[cellY]

   # line is being evaluated/separated at every " "
   myArray = np.fromstring(line, dtype = float, sep = ' ')

   # picks out the right "column" from my array
   cellValue = myArray[cellX] 

   if cellValue == -9999.0:
       print("This cell is at sea ! ! ! ")
   elif cellValue != -9999.0:
       print("Cell value found: " + str(cellValue))
```

`

Comment: There is a GDAL utility for this purpose https://gdal.org/programs/gdallocationinfo.html if you do not want to write your own.

Comment: While it's called "Esri ASCII raster format" it was actually developed with several other companies, and does not require ArcGIS to read; most GIS tools can read ASCII rasters.

Comment: rasterio has a nice function for this:  https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.sample.html#module-rasterio.sample

Comment: @vince That is good to know. Any suggestion of a GIS tool that could handle this smoothly?

Comment: @mikewatt The function you suggest seems to require a x.y-set input in the datasets reference system. To calculate that x,y-set from long/lat is one of the things I have not yet figured out.

Comment: Did you try it, just supplying lon/lat directly?  I know it says x/y in the docs, but rasterio applies the inverse geotransform which should do exactly that for you (if I understand correctly).

Comment: here's a useful question that has some good answers: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62343/how-can-i-convert-a-ascii-file-to-geotiff-using-python  gdal is easy to install.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will try gdal and rasterio as soon as I can and put an update on here. I am currently on a boat with minimal internet connection stopping me from downloading.

Answer (score 1):

Gdal is a great tool. You can do it manually, however.

the following method is copied from https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html  which  is a good gdal+python reference.

```
def world2Pixel(geoMatrix, x, y):
  """
  Uses a gdal geomatrix (gdal.GetGeoTransform()) to calculate
  the pixel location of a geospatial coordinate
  """
  ulX = geoMatrix[0]
  ulY = geoMatrix[3]
  xDist = geoMatrix[1]
  yDist = geoMatrix[5]
  rtnX = geoMatrix[2]
  rtnY = geoMatrix[4]
  pixel = int((x - ulX) / xDist)
  line = int((ulY - y) / xDist)
  return (pixel, line)
```

If you don't have gdal, you can re-create your own geoMatrix based on the headers of your ascii file.

```
'''

your values
ncols         4
nrows         6
xllcorner     0.0
yllcorner     0.0
cellsize      50.0
NODATA_value  -9999
'''

def world2Pixel_yours(x, y):
  ulX = 0.0
  ulY = 0.0 + 6 * 50.0
  xDist = 50.0
  yDist = 50.0

  pixel_x = int((x - ulX) / xDist)
  pixel_y = int((ulY - y) / yDist)
  return (pixel_x, pixel_y)
```

Disclaimer...I did not test this.  I hope that it's enough to get you started though.

*another disclaimer* (mikewatt) is that this approach doesn't factor in any possible rotation in a raster. If your geotransform matrix has values in [2] or [4] positions than you'd best either brush up on some geometry or look for another pre-made function.

Comment: This kind of approach is fine for the OP where the format doesn't support rotation (am I correct in that?) but for anyone else this could be important, it's not a general solution to the problem for any raster.

Comment: @mikewatt absolutely true. However, 2 things: 1) I'm trying to help solve his problem, not future problems of other people. and 2) In my years of using rasters, I have never had a rotated one.  That said, I agree with your comment and will edit my answer to indicate there is more to it.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion, will do some testing(I have edited some details in my question). Seems like world2pixel() takes long/lat coordinates as input and returns x,y pixel coordinates for the file in question? If that is the case I suppose I could use world2pixel() in combination with another function that returns the value I'm seeking

Comment: @nik  oh, I see your edits...you'll need to adjust accordingly. And, yes, to get the value of the raster cell you will need to access it by using the returned row/col pair.